Insert Map frame not loading in ArcGIS Pro
I have been trying to add a map frame for a layout and all I get is the loading wheel. I had one map frame already loaded and was able to copy-paste this map to create other layouts. However, any attempt at looking at the map frame properties crashed the program, ArcGIS Pro 3.3.0.
Do you have any ideas on solutions?


Delete the layout and start again?

Current Work Around copy and paste the map frame already in the layout and use that. (Will crash the program if you try and change properties.)
